# Where in the page does Angular load scripts?

Tags: javascript, angular

I have an Angular 6 project that references a custom Javascript file using the **angular.json** file. Everything works as expected, but I need to ensure that this **custom.js** file gets loaded in the **body** of the page as opposed to the **head**. Angular does not show this when I right-click on the page to view source. Is it correct to assume that scripts are loaded in the body by default?
This is what **view source** reveals:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
   <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <title>AngularJavascriptDemo</title>
      <base href="/">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
      <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
   </head>
   <body>
      <app-root></app-root>
      <script src="runtime.js" type="module"></script>
      <script src="polyfills.js" type="module"></script>
      <script src="styles.js" type="module"></script>
      <script src="scripts.js" defer></script>
      <script src="vendor.js" type="module"></script>
      <script src="main.js" type="module"></script>
   </body>
</html>
```

I need to ensure that the page loads optimally.

Comment: @DonJuwe Did you read the text? He said referenced it inside the angular.json file. He just doesn't know where it ends up on build.

Comment: [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) _"Asking a question on Stack Overflow should be the last step in your process for finding an answer"_ Have you read https://angular.io/guide/workspace-config? I assume you've added the script to `projects/architect/build/options/scripts`. That's described https://angular.io/guide/workspace-config#additional-build-and-test-options and https://angular.io/guide/workspace-config#style-script-config

Comment: In the documentation you'll find that the scripts are injected into index.html. _"Is it safe to assume that scripts are loaded in the body by default?"_ It's not documented so it depends on you. Is an undocumented behavior safe for you? The exact place is not even specified in the unit tests: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/blob/a78eaad91af890e285accd4566e0c30c704c5efc/packages/angular_devkit/build_angular/src/browser/tests/options/scripts_spec.ts

Comment: @ThomasSablik I hope you have read my question generously and understood it. Your first comment suggest that I am asking a ridiculously easy question, but in your second comment you speak of configurations (which is out of the scope of my question). You further state that what I am asking is not documented (and this is exactly why I posted the question). It is a no brainer that scripts go into the index.html but my question is  where in the page meaning (body or head)

Comment: _"in your second comment you speak of configurations (which is out of the scope of my question)"_ It isn't out of the scope. `"inject": false` and `"inject": true` will behave differently. My comments tried to say you that it's not specified and it depends on you if unspecified behavior is safe. Is it safe for you if the code is written in a specific way? Currently the scripts are loaded into the body but if someone would change it tomorrow it wouldn't be wrong because the unit tests don't test the position and the position is not mentioned in the documentation.

Comment: @ThomasSablik I see where the confusion lies. This is not a question about safety. I am asking if it is **correct** (not safe) to assume that by default the compiler loads scripts in the body of the index.html

Comment: The current version of Angular uses [HtmlWebpackPlugin](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/html-webpack-plugin/) to create the index.html and add the scripts. You can see it in the source code, e.g. [here](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/blob/e871f87fa2eda5cdf74557b95b47aa419e53e17b/packages/angular_devkit/build_angular/src/webpack/configs/common.ts) The documentation of the current version of HtmlWebpackPlugin says: _"The plugin will generate an HTML5 file for you that includes all your webpack bundles in the body using script tags."_ Now you could do the same research for Angular 6.